# Data Frame with unique pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a dataFrame(just a column) which has vehicle brands and its models like, `Toyota Rav4`, `Kia Soul`, (brand and models at the same column), I want to show all of Volvo's models.
Output should be like that,

```
Volvo xc90
Volvo xc60
Volvo V90
.
.
.
```

What is the best coding?

Comment: Does the make ever have spaces in? (e.g. `Vol vo`, similar to that)?

Comment: just have, between brand and model like "Audi A4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.contains('Volvo')`.
Demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Volvo xc90', 'Volvo xc60', 'Volvo V90', 'abc'])
df[df[0].str.contains('Volvo')]
```

[image]

Comment: This is simple which is nice, but if `Volvo` happened to appear as the start of a *different* company's cars, e.g. `Toyota Volvosomething`... I know it's highly unlikely but it's something to take into consideration.

Comment: In that case you can add a blank at the start and end of Volvo.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.str.split`:

```
filtered = df[df['car'].str.split().str[0] == 'Volvo']
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
          car
0  Volvo xc90
2  Volvo xc60
4   Volvo V90
```